# Saving a jqPlot graph to an image file

Tags: javascript, image, save, jqplot, mouseclick-event

I am using jqPlot to display many graphs on some webpages. I am wanting to be able to save these graphs to an image file.

What is the best way to do this? Is it possible to have a right click menu option on the graph that enables the graph to be saved to an image file?

Here is some code for one of my graphs:

```
var plotCogsLineGraph = $.jqplot('FinancialsLineGraph', [[30,31,34,40,45], [34,38,31,42,38]], 
{ 
            axes:
            {
                xaxis:
                {
                      ticks: ['5','4','3','2','1']
                },
                yaxis:
                {
                    label:'%',
                    pad: 1.05,
                    ticks: ['0','15','30','45','60']
                }
            },

            width: 480, height: 270,
            legend:{show:true, location: 's', placement: 'insideGrid', renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer},
    seriesDefaults: 
    {
                rendererOptions: {smooth: true}
    },
    series:[ 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'COGS',
                    markerOptions: { size:1, style:'dimaond' }
                }, 
                {
                    lineWidth:1, 
                    label:'Wages',
                    markerOptions: { size: 1, style:"dimaond" }
                }
                ]
    }
);
```

What needs to be added to this above code to enable saving the graph to an image file?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$('#FinancialsLineGraph').jqplotSaveImage()
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your plot is drawing in a div with 'plot' id.
You have to apply native `jqplotToImageStr({})` function in order to convert the plot to an image.
Then you can fill an other div (with id = 'graphicImage' for example) in order to display this freshly generated image :

```
var graphicImage = $('#graphicImage');
if(graphicImage.html() == ""){ //If the image was even generated, don't generate it again
  var divGraph = $('#plot').jqplotToImageStr({});
  var divElem  = $('<img/>').attr('src', divGraph);
  graphicImage.html(divElem);
}
```

In order to download the image, you can do something like :

```
   open(divGraph.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

In my case it doesn't work great as the image downloaded on my computer is corrupted.
If you find a way to save it I'll be great to hear about it.

Anyway, once you have done the first part on this answer (fill the '#graphicImage' div with the image corresponding to jqplot), you can save it thanks to a right click on it...

Comment: I am getting an error at line: var divElem  = $('<img/>).attr('src', divGraph);

Comment: The quote isn't terminated around <img/> tag

Comment: to download try this <a href="print content of 'divGraph' here" download="fileName">Download</a>

Answer (score 1):

`$('#GraphName').jqplotSaveImage()`  but aware that if you have applied some custom styles on ticks this won't be saved to image